# HoloLens 2 Can't connect using Microsoft HoloLens Windows 10 Desktop App

Tags: hololens

Anyone else having issues attempting to stream Hololens 2 using the Microsoft HoloLens desktop app?

I put in the IP of the hololens and it connects because my hololens will give me the pin.

I proceed to create username and password and immediately the Microsoft HoloLens app says, "We can't connect to (HOLOLENS NAME). Edit your device's IP address, user name or password, if they have changed, to reconnect."

I can connect to the hololens no problem using a browser by going to "https://(hololensIP)" and logging in. When I restart the hololens using the browser, I can connect for 2 seconds as soon as it starts up, but then it kicks me out and gives me the same message as before.

Anyone else experience this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tracking issue, and our PG team is working to get a fix for this in future OS update for the HoloLens device.

For now, the temporary workaround is to get a new IP address for the device and retry again from the dashboard. Then, enter the new IP address in the HoloLens desktop app. If it still cannot work after trying this solution, please feel free to feedback.